# Quais as maneiras de evitar recursividade infinita sem o uso da anotação JsonIgnore no SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot

Tenho uma relação `@OneToMany` entre `Produto` e `TipoProduto` onde um `TipoProduto` pode ter vários `Produto`s e um `Produto` pode ter apenas um `TipoProduto`.

Eu gostaria de listar todos os `Produto`s de um `TipoProduto` quando pesquisasse sobre ele e também gostaria de listar o `TipoProduto` de um `Produto` quando pesquisasse por ele. Tentei sobrescrever o método `toString()` porém sem sucesso. Tive algumas ideias porém não sei se são válidas, então gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de evitar isso ou então o problema está no design de minha aplicação.

`TipoProduto`:

```
public class TipoProduto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tipoProduto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Produto> produtos;
    ....
}
```

`Produto`:

```
public class Produto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_produto_id", nullable = true)
    private TipoProduto tipoProduto;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Por que não é boa ideia transformar entidades em JSON diretamente

O erro está em querer transformar suas entidades do JPA em JSON. Já participei de um projeto que atrasou meses só por causa disso.

Transformar as entidades JPA em JSON é problemático por conta de:

- Problemas de laços - é difícil saber-se quem é o pai e quem é o filho. Por vezes, em alguns casos você vai querer os filhos dizendo quem são os pais e por vezes vai querer os pais dizendo quem são os filhos.
- O formato da entidade JPA nem sempre é o mesmo do formato desejado no JSON. Por exemplo, se você tem uma entidade `Usuario` com um campo `senha`, não vai querer o campo `senha` aparecendo no JSON. Se você tem uma entidade `Vendedor` e você quer saber quantas vendas ele realizou no mês, o JSON ficaria enorme e poluído com todas as informações sobre vendas quando a única coisa que você quer é saber quantas vendas são.
- Você não consegue contextualizar o JSON, de forma que tenha um conjunto com determinadas informações em um contexto e um conjunto diferente de informações em outro contexto.
- Há casos onde os dados que você precisa exportar ou importar não correspondem diretamente a nenhuma de suas entidades.

Todos esses problemas advém do fato de que o mapeamento JPA serve para fazer o mapeamento objeto-relacional da aplicação, enquanto que o mapeamento objeto-JSON tem uma finalidade completamente diferente. Colocando os dois nas mesmas classes, você acaba fazendo um mapeamento das tabelas do banco de dados para o JSON, o que normalmente não é o que você quer fazer.

## A solução

A solução é criar um grupo de classes em paralelo para representar o seu JSON. Em um outro projeto diferente do que citei acima, ao utilizarmos essa abordagem não tivemos praticamente nenhum problema com o JSON e essa parte do projeto foi extremamente tranquila e simples de se trabalhar.

No meio do projeto, separamos essas classes que representam o JSON em uma biblioteca a parte para não correr o risco de misturar (de vez em quando acontecia por acidente). Ao separá-las, qualquer tentativa de misturá-las com as entidades tornou-se um erro de compilação, pois o pacote com as entidades tinha dependência com o pacote das classess que representam o JSON, mas o inverso não.

Por exemplo:

```java
public final class ProdutoJSON {
    private final String nome;
    private final Long id;
    private final String descricaoTipo;
    private final Long idTipo;

    public ProdutoJSON(String nome, Long id, String descricaoTipo, Long idTipo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
        this.descricaoTipo = descricaoTipo;
        this.idTipo = idTipo;
    }

    // Acrescente os getters aqui.
}
```

```java
public final class TipoProdutoJSON {
    private final String descricao;
    private final Long id;
    private final List<ProdutoPorTipoJSON> produtosListados;

    public TipoProdutoJSON(String descricao, Long id, List<ProdutoPorTipoJSON> produtosListados) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.id = id;
        this.produtosListados = produtosListados;
    }

    // Acrescente os getters aqui.
}
```

```java
public final class ProdutoPorTipoJSON {
    private final String nome;
    private final Long id;

    public ProdutoPorTipoJSON(String nome, Long id) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Acrescente os getters aqui.
}
```

Observe que as classes acima são apenas um monte de dados crus e elas têm uma estrutura imutável. Isso ocorre porque a única finalidade delas existirem é a de apenas serem usadas para estruturar JSONs e nada mais que isso. Elas devem ter a estrutura desejada do JSON sem nada a mais e nada menos, e portanto, não se preocupe muito em reutilizá-las. Podem ser modeladas ao gosto da sua ferramenta, seja ela Jackson, GSON ou qualquer outra que você estiver usando, ficando essas classes livres de quaisquer restrições ou regras do JPA.

Eis como você instancia essas classes a partir de suas entidades:

```java
public class TipoProduto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String descricao;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tipoProduto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Produto> produtos;

    // ...

    public TipoProdutoJSON criarJsonComProdutos() {
        List<ProdutoPorTipoJSON> p = produtos
                .stream()
                .map(Produto::criarJsonSemTipoProduto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new TipoProdutoJSON(descricao, id, p);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Produto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_produto_id", nullable = true)
    private TipoProduto tipoProduto;

    // ...

    public ProdutoPorTipoJSON criarJsonSemTipoProduto() {
        return new ProdutoPorTipoJSON(nome, id);
    }

    public ProdutoJSON criarJsonComTipoProduto() {
        return new ProdutoJSON(
                nome,
                id,
                tipoProduto == null ? null : tipoProduto.getDescricao(),
                tipoProduto == null ? null : tipoProduto.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: O seu exemplo fere algumas diretrizes de design do REST, tal como quando cita a relação de `Vendedor` com `Venda`. Apesar de existir relação entre os recursos, caso queira visualizar as vendas de um vendedor, o jeito mais eficiente de se trabalhar isso seria através do caminho `/vendedores/{id}/vendas`, não retornando os objetos de forma implícita. Isso evita vários problemas de desperdício tanto de memória quanto de tráfego de dados na rede.

Comment: @WeslleyTavares Não. Quando você usa o caminho `vendedores/{id}/vendas`, um serviço irá responder por essa URL, buscar o vendedor correspondente com `Vendedor v = em.find(id);` e então produzir a lista dos objetos a serem serializados com `List<VendaPorVendedorJSON> lista = v.listarJsonVendas();`. Não há nenhum aumento no tráfego de rede com isso e o mapeamento do REST permanece inalterado.

Comment: Quanto ao consumo de memória, depende do caso. Mas nessa abordagem acima, o consumo tende a ser menor devido ao fato de que ao transformar a entidade em um JSON, você provavelmente vai acabar acessando várias partes do grafo do objeto trazido pelo JPA, produzindo um JSON inchado que ocupa mais memória e tende a ser mais pesado em trafegar. É verdade que não é necessariamente isso acontecerá, mas é muito fácil controlar isso mapeando-se o JSON em objetos a parte, enquanto que é muito difícil controlar isso mapeando-se o JSON diretamente nas entidades.

Comment: Valeu @VictorStafusa, já tinha lido algo sobre isso, isso se assemelha ao padrão DTO certo?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Se assemelha tanto que é exatamente dele que estamos falando. :) - Essas classes a parte são nada mais nada menos que DTOs.

Comment: haha, Entendi. valeu! A resposta foi bem esclarecedora.

Answer (score 2):

Muito possivelmente a sua aplicação está com um problema de design, já que está sofrendo com esse problema de referência circular (ou dependência circular, como alguns chamam).

Se for o caso de reestruturar o design, caberia a velha pergunta:

> No caso das duas entidades, em um cenário de exclusão de uma delas, quem continua viva sem depender da outra?

Agora se a solução implementada por você estiver inerente ao negócio da aplicação, pouca coisa se pode fazer em relação ao design.

Para esses casos, existem várias "soluções de contorno" (famosos workarounds).

No contexto do Spring, dê uma olhada [neste excelente material](http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring). Dentre as várias opções que ele mostra, escolha uma que melhor se adeque ao seu cenário.

Dos casos que o autor cita, já utilizei a que referencia o método `set` para fazer a injeção dos beans.